# Undefined method checked using checkboxes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a checkbox in rails such that I get multiple checkbox values for storing in the database. After searching I found out we can use check_box_tag for this purpose. Here is the statement. The problem is that I am getting:

```
undefined method `checked' for #<#<Class:0x60aa268>:0xa1e0f80>
Did you mean?  check_box
```

I have tried normal checkbox and it works. I am using rails 5. Any ideas?

Code:

```
    <%=check_box_tag 'datahandler[products][]', c.product_name, checked(c.product_name), id: c.product_id %>
```

Comment: Indeed, method `checked` seems to be not defined. Do you, perhaps, have an _array_ `checked`?

Comment: No I haven't defined any array with the name checked.

Comment: Anyhow, the third parameter of `check_box_tag` accepts a boolean value, which will determine the pre-checked state of the input. Find a way to get this boolean value for each product name (whatever makes sense for your app). If you don't want any checkboxes to be prechecked, just pass `false` or pass nothing at all.

Comment: Okay I get the idea. Thanks.

Comment: You also might want to look at `collection_check_boxes` if you are looking for multiple check boxes.  https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: When Rails sees a method like in your case `checked` it will look for a helper method named `checked`. It could be that you don't have method `checked` defined on some file under your `app/helpers` directory.

And yes as Sergio mentioned in the comment above the third parameter of `check_box_tag` should be `true` or `false`, which would mean that method `checked` should return one of those values.

Comment: @JohnBaker exactly I haven't defined the checked method in app/helpers directory, the problem is then because of them

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name %>
```